# programmatically add line item of commerce_discount type to order

Tags: commerce

I want to programmatically add line item of commerce_doscount type to my order, I test below code,it is correctly add a record to line items array but not show in  order list even I refresh the order I dont see anything in order table .

```
$amount = trim($amount);
  $basePrice = commerce_price_field_data_auto_creation();
  $basePrice['amount'] = $amount;
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
if ($amount) {
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
     $line_item = entity_create('commerce_line_item', array(
    'type' => 'commerce_discount',
    'line_item_label' => 'my test',
    'quantity' => 1,
));
    // Wrap the line item and product to easily set field information.
$line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
// Set the unit price on the line item object.
$basePrice = commerce_price_field_data_auto_creation();
$basePrice['amount'] = $amount;
  $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price = $basePrice;
// Save the line item now so we get its ID.
  commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

      //  $line_item = commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
        // Add it to the order's line item reference value.
$order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
     //commerce_order_save($wrapper);
      commerce_order_save($order);
$order = commerce_order_load($order->order_id);

        // Recalculate discounts.
      //  ym($order);
        commerce_cart_order_refresh($order);
```

also I look at `discount` module and try below code

```
 module_load_include('inc', 'commerce_discount', 'commerce_discount.rules');
   $amount = trim($amount);
  $basePrice = commerce_price_field_data_auto_creation();
  $basePrice['amount'] = $amount;
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  commerce_discount_add_line_item($order_wrapper,'commerce_discount',$basePrice);
```

but return me **EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to get the data property commerce_total as the parent data structure is not set. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue()**

Comment: "it is correctly add a record to line items array" - if record is not displayed, then either you are wrong and it adds it incorrectly, or there is some kind of cache that prevents you from seeing changes.

Comment: it's just interesting to me, what is `ym()` function in your code?

Comment: `ym` in my short name :). I have tiny developing module to provide some jobs like `dsm` and some tiny features, sometimes I dont need heavy devel module :).

Comment: @Mołot I dont think the cache is problem, because discount and coupon module do it , I look  discount module and want to use it but return me error, I come code in update question

Comment: @xurshid29 but it is very old version of my module, I improve it and add more features :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, here. Discounts provides functions for apply discounts to orders:

```
// Pass in an $order or $product that has been entity_metadata_wrapper()ed.
// And pass in a discount name.
commerce_discount_fixed_amount(EntityDrupalWrapper $wrapper, $discount_name);

// Same thing, but a percentage.
commerce_discount_percentage(EntityDrupalWrapper $wrapper, $discount_name);
```

If you must reinvent the wheel, use these functions as examples to guide what you are doing.

Comment: I didn't find this  functions in  discount module when I ask this question :D .

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version. Also, check in the commerce_discount.rules.inc file for these functions.

Comment: look at the question date, I resolve it in that time, tnx for your attention.